# Performance of foreach vs. Where().Select()

Tags: c#, performance, foreach

---

This question is about comparison between foreach and Linq methods from performance point of view. 

The code i bring below is just an example I have currently.

---

Is there an advantage of using .Where().Select() over foreach loop (from performance point-of-view)?

I have this C# block and i would like to improve performance here:

```
var resultList = new List<MyItemWrapper>();
foreach (var key in KeysCollection)
{
    if (SomeCondition(key))
    {
        var anotherKey = CreateAnotherKey(key);
        if (AnotherCondition(anotherKey))
        {
            resultList.Add(new MyItemWrapper { Id = key });
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use Where().Select() and also tried to do that AsPArallel() but no improveent in performance. On contrary, i see that performance getting worst.

```
var resultList = KeysCollection
                    .Where(key =>
                    {
                        if (!SomeCondition(key))
                            return false;

                        var anotherKey = CreateAnotherKey(key);
                        return AnotherCondition(anotherKey);
                    })
                    .Select(key => new MyItemWrapper { Id = key })
                    .ToList();
```

Notes:

- the `SomeCondition()` and `AnotherCondition()` should be treated as blackboxes.
- the returned `resultList` should be an `IList`.
- the `KeysCollection` is of type `ICollection`

Can someone please help and give tips to improve this?

Comment: Have you run your code through the profiler to see where the bottleneck is? How many keys are you dealing with? Maybe the slowness is in one of those black box methods, in which case your loop construct isn't going to make any difference.

Comment: Looks like you can simple use https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet and post results into this question

Comment: The Linq methods essentially just call `foreach` loops anyway, why would you think it would perform better?  I imagine `CreateAnotherKey()` and/or `AnotherCondition()` are the bottlenecks...

Comment: Thanks all for the comments.

My main question is about performance of foreach vs. LINQ methods. if there is any clear advantage in any of them over the other.
Not about the blackbox methods.

What about AsParallel() which should allow us to run in parallel? why it doesn't help as well? I also tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq is not designed to improve *performance*. It is designed to improve *coding efficiency*. It can, in some cases, be more performant than *bad* loops (e.g. when you are looking for the existence of an item, `Any` will stop when an item is found, but a bad loop may continue looping), but in general it will not improve performance.

So use whatever you understand better (IMHO the where delegate you use is much harder to understand) and use Linq to *improve* readability.

If you have *identified* a performance problem, then get a good profiler to determine where the most time is being spend. I'd be surprised if the Linq methods are actually a bottleneck.

That said, you could *also* structure the query this way:

```
var reslutList = KeysCollection.Where(key => SomeCondition(key))
                               .Where(key => AnotherCondition(CreateAnotherKey(key)))
                               .Select(key => new MyItemWrapper { Id = key })
                               .ToList();
```

Which *might* be easier to understand than either the loop or the custom delegate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer.

so it sounds like that: "there is no advantage in performance for using LINQ but it is more for readability".
Is this a right statement?

But what about AsParallel() which should allow us to run in parallel? why it doesn't help as well? I also tried it.

Comment: `AsParallel` only helps _CPU bound_ processes. If your process is not pegging the CPU but has other bottlenecks (memory, I/O, network, etc.) then `AsParallel` will probably not help.